Programming SNMP Monitoring Scripts for Legacy PNNI/ATM Networks with MGX Switches
I'm working on developing a Python monitoring script to interface with our legacy ATM network using SNMP. Specifically, I would like to monitor the PNNI routing states on Cisco MGX switches with PXM cards.
Here's my current code attempt:

Need help identifying correct MIB OIDs for PNNI routing table entries

"No Such Instance currently exists" errors when querying PXM cards


from pysnmp.hlapi import *

def get_pnni_state(switch_ip):
    iterator = getCmd(
        SnmpEngine(),
        CommunityData('public', mpModel=0),
        UdpTransportTarget((switch_ip, 161)),
        ContextData(),
        ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('CISCO-WAN-ATM-CONN-MIB::cwaConnState'))
    )
    errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(iterator)
    return varBinds[0][1] if not errorIndication else None


Please contact Cisco customer support. This isn’t a device widely used by programmers so people here cannot reproduce or investigate for you.
